# element-wise combinations from large files

Tags: r, large-files

I have 12 ASCII files, each consisting of a tensor of dimension [8760, 361, 181] (about 10 Gb each). I need to combine these 12 tensors to a create a single one where each element is the nth quantile  (for example the median) of the 12.

for example, a simple function would be:

```
f.Quantile(...){
dat <- do.call(cbind, list(...))
res <- rowQuantiles(dat, na.rm = T, probs = 0.5) 
return(res)
}
```

but the problem is that I would need to load all the files at once, which is impossible given their size and my computational resources. 
Therefore, I'd be grateful if you could suggest a way to read the files sequentially, without loading them completely. for example, open up all the files, read ONLY the 1st element of each and calculate the median. The same for the second element, and so forth. After several tests, I'm using 'scan' to open the files:

```
scan(file, what=numeric(), sep='', na.strings ="-9.000000E+00" , quiet=T)
```

but can only open two before getting 'out of memory'.

Any idea welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I used the LaF-package for large files. Might help in your case.

Comment: `mstrsplit`, `read.chunk` and `chunk.reader` from `iotools` may be what you are looking for. See the examples [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-001/index.html). The examples does not match your problem as you have multiple sources but may still be useful.